# How should I call the 'startActionMode' method?

Tags: java, android

I want use ActionMode to change my ActionBar. But I have a problem with `startActionMode`. It shows me an error:

> Error:(28, 65) error: incompatible types:
>   MainActivity.ActionBarCallBack cannot be converted to Callback

I don't know how I should use this as samples.

```
package ferdos.androidui.activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActionMode mActionMode;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu2);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mActionMode = MainActivity.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
            }
        });
    }

    class ActionBarCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback {

        @Override...  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, you have to replace the method `startActionMode` to  `startSupportActionMode`